# Short story about a fantasy creature zoo with a centaur man

Tags: story-identification, centaurs

A long time ago I read a short story anthology. One of the stories was about a man who had been injured and they'd rebuilt him as a centaur but he had to live in this zoo of fantasy creatures and have sex with patrons. In the story, he has sex with a female patron and female centaur at the same time. He breaks his leg at the end of the story trying to escape. It was an old book. Print.

Comment: Hey, welcome! You have a nice start here, but you can increase your chances of getting an answer if you provide a little more information. Any detail, no matter how insignificant it may seen, can help! Do you remember anything about the author? You say it's "old"; how old? When was a "long time ago"? Do you remember anything about any other stories in the anthology? What other creatures were in the zoo? How was the man injured? Who rebuilt him?

Answer (score 3):

The story is "Elfleda" by Vonda MacIntyre. The story is just as you describe it - the main character was injured and remade as a centaur, along with many other creatures like fauns, nymphs, pegasus and mermaids, and lives in a large zoo. Occasionally their masters arrive and "play" with them, which usually ends up in an orgy. He is desperately in love with Elfleda, a unicorn-centaur, and becomes jealous when she goes off with an ugly "master" boy. He does have a four-way eventually, and at the end tries to escape but falls, breaks his leg, and is killed by the masters.

It has been anthologized in New Dimensions 12 (1981) and Unicorns! (1982)
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!